# Specific class for generated-members in pylint?

Tags: python, pylint

I'm slightly unsure of how the `generated-members` of pylint works.

Lets say I add the following to `.pylintrc`:

```
[TYPECHECK]
generated-members=commit
```

It hides the following `commit` error:

> E1101:Instance of 'scoped_session' has no 'commit' member

However, this hides `commit` errors in general, from what I understand. Can I somehow specify the exact class member with `generated-members`? For example (pseudo):

```
[TYPECHECK]
generated-members=sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session.commit
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. The code

```
db.session.add(item)
db.session.commit()
```

causes pylint errors:

```
[pylint] E1101:Instance of 'scoped_session' has no 'add' member
[pylint] E1101:Instance of 'scoped_session' has no 'commit' member
```

I added the following string in `pylintrc`

```
generated-members=db.session.*
```

and errors disappear.

Comment: I was having this issue with db.Column and the various db column types.  I added them specifically: db.Column, db.Integer, db.String, ... to generated-members and the errors went away