# Flask Error: db: scoped_session Instance of 'scoped_session' has no 'commit' memberpylint(no-member)

Tags: python, flask

I'm doing a Flask course but when I run this code, it throws an error:

```py
for origin, destination, duration in reader:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO flights (origin, destination, duration) VALUES (:origin, :destination, :duration)",
                    {"origin": origin, "destination": destination, "duration": duration})
        print(f"Added flight from {origin} to {destination} lasting {duration} minutes.")
db.commit()
```

The error in the last line (db.commit(), and db.execute()):

```
db: scoped_session
Instance of 'scoped_session' has no 'commit' memberpylint(no-member)
```

What can I do to fix it? I already installed the package sqlalchemy that other questions suggests.

Comment: Why does it end in "pylint(no-member)"?  Are you running the code itself, or are your running it somehow through pylint?

Comment: The error appear in vscode

Comment: I just open the file and throws

Comment: I'm 99% sure that that isn't true. You haven't shown how you set up the connection

Comment: https://imgur.com/2WxEusw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specific class for generated-members in pylint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168479/specific-class-for-generated-members-in-pylint)

Comment: Try actually running the code.  This is just VSCode giving an "error" in advance based on some static analysis, but it does not necessarily mean there's a real error.  I believe this to be a possible false-positive.  Did you actually *run* the code or is this just based on on what VSCode is telling you in the editor?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error is thrown by **Pylint** which is a static code checker, it can introduce false positives at times, it does not mean that your code does not work.

You need to tell pylint to ignore scoped_session by adding this line to the .pylintrc file:

```
ignored-classes=scoped_session
```

If you don't have a .pylintrc file, you can run this:

```
 pylint --generate-rcfile > pylintrc
```

Comment: @roganjosh looks like he's running it through pylint, look at the error he's getting(memberpylint):
Instance of 'scoped_session' has no 'commit' memberpylint(no-member)

Comment: Yeah, this is correct.  They're not even running the code, it's just pylint in VSCode giving a static checker error.

Comment: @roganjosh your comments here are quite annoying given the fact that you are wrong... I actually ran into the same problem (yes, without running my code!! still got me wondering...), knowing that pylint is just pylint and not the interpreter itself. 

Alternatively one can do `#pylint:disable=no-member`  for the lines in question. However I find Dani's answer more compelling.

Comment: @Robert deleted